# When printing an externally selected pdf from my code, a watermark 'PDFControls.NET 2.0 PRO' gets added to the printout

Tags: c#, pdf

In my program, the user has an option to select from file explorer, a pdf to be printed without a dialog being displayed. When printing it from the code, it outputs a watermark 'PDFControls.NET 2.0 PRO' in the pdf printer. If the same pdf is printed from the program, with a print dialog, then there is no watermark.

Uploading and printing an Excel file does not have this issue.

When generating the pdf document in the code, then printing this from the code does not add a watermark on the pdf printout.

I am using TallComponents

```
    public void Print( OtherDoc otherDoc )
    {
        try
        {
            using ( FileStream sourceFile = new FileStream( otherDoc.Uri, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None ) )
            {
                var pdfDoc = new PDF.Document(sourceFile, otherDoc.Password);

                this.PrintDoc( pdfDoc );
            }

            this.PrintResult = PdfPrintResult.Success;
        }
        catch ( System.UnauthorizedAccessException )
        {
            this.PrintResult = PdfPrintResult.EditFail;
        }
        catch ( System.Exception e )
        {
            this.PrintResult = PdfPrintResult.GeneralFail;
            this.PrintError = e.Message;
        }
    }


    private void PrintDoc( PDF.Document pdfDoc )
    {
        PDF.Printing.PrintSettings printSettings = new PDF.Printing.PrintSettings();
        pdfDoc.Print( printSettings );
    }
```

It is printing a watermark on the pdf ''PDFControls.NET 2.0 PRO' but should not print any watermark on the pdf

Comment: Email the authors, would be my first choice, its probably some trial ware or limited version or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are using the trial. If you have a license, make sure you've added your license key to your web.config or app.config as described [here](https://www.tallcomponents.com/pdfcontrols/use-multiple-licenses).

```
<configuration>
    <appsettings>
        <add key="PDFKit.NET 4.0 Server Key" value="7206:JUm8jYm-4bwE84gi8RtQuk++" />
    </appsettings>
</configuration>
```

If you have already done that, then you'll have to [contact TallComponents](https://www.tallcomponents.com/contact) for support.

Comment: This has fixed the issue where I am printing a pdf using `ShellExecute(NULL_HWND,"print",file,EMPTY_SHELLEX_PARAMS, dir, SW_HIDE );`

However it did not fix the problem where I am printing using TallComponents:
        `private void PrintDoc( PDF.Document pdfDoc )
        {
            PDF.Printing.PrintSettings printSettings = new PDF.Printing.PrintSettings();
            pdfDoc.Print( printSettings );
        }`

PDF is namespace TallComponents.PDF

Comment: You will have to ask the company then.